# How does sqlalchemy as_declarative base objects link itself to db Metadata object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
# in base_obj file
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

# in user_table file
from base_obj import Base

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user_table"
    user_id = Column(String(255), primary_key))
```

This `Base` object is in one file, and the other subclasses of `Base`, such as `User` are in separated files. At first, all of these files where in a python package and everything were fine.
But I needed to put all my `Base` objects inside a python module which I would install by a `pip install git+ssh://my_repo`.
My interpreter is still able to access of each `Base` subclasse objects separately. But the `Base.metadata.tables` is empty.

It looks like sqlalchemy is no longer able to link sqlalchemy `Base` objects to the `Metadata` and the db engine. It makes then impossible to create the database tables.

Does anyone knows how sqlalchemy performs this link?
That would greatly help.

Comment: You should only have a *single* `Base` across your entire app. Multiple `Base`s are for extremely advanced scenarios, not for code splitting. Or do you mean you have other `Base` *subclasses* in separate files?

Comment: The `Base` you see in my code is the only one that I use, and I import it in all python files where I need to construct a base object

Comment: `User` is a `Base` *subclass*. It's very confusing to refer to them as `Base` objects. But anyway, `declarative_base` takes in a metadata object and creates one if you don't pass in one. Where is the metadata object you are defining?

Comment: I have not created one, so I used the one created with `declarative_base`. I will change the wording of base objects, which indeed is confusing, thanks

Comment: Then that means you haven't imported the modules that contain your `Base` subclasses from your entry point.

Comment: the `Base` subclasses are contained in `base_objects.direct`, the `Base` is in `base_objects.base_obj`
In the python REPL I used these commands:
`> from base_objects.direct import *`
`> from base_objects.base_obj import Base`
`> engine = create_engine("my_url")`
`> Base.metadata.bind = engine`
`> Base.metadata.create_all(engine)`
But I still end up with the same result

Comment: What's `base_objects.direct` and how is it related to `user_table`?

Comment: `base_objects.direct` is the name of the package that contains each `Base` subclasses. `User` is in `base_objects.direc.user_table.py`

Comment: And have you imported `base_objects.direct.user_table` in `base_objects.direct`?

Comment: yes, I used in my `__init__.py` `from user_table import User`.
But This code was in production for over six months. I created a python package with a `setup.py`. By installing `base_objects` with pip, it seemed I crippled the hability of sqlalchemy to link each `Base` subclasses to its parent

Comment: Does your working directory contain the package `base_objects`? I think what might be happening is that you're importing two separate copies of `Base`, once as `base_obj.Base`, then as `base_objects.base_obj.Base`, from two separate locations on the file system. Can you try `cd`ing to a completely unrelated directory (one that doesn't contain `base_objects`, `direct`, `base_obj`, or `user_table`), ensure you don't have weird entries in `sys.path`, and try it again?

Comment: @univerio tried what you advised. I performed the same tasks in a different directory. Nothing changed `Base.metadata.tables = immutableDict({})`. And my `path` looks clean, only python2.7 site-packages references from virtualenv.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Can you try to distill your code down to a [mcve], complete with a `setup.py`?